# Windows no longer starts on HDDs / SSDs cloned from McAfee encrypted HDDs / SSDs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, encryption, clone

As suggested in [Considerations when using imaging software with Endpoint Encryption software](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB51979) and reported by many experts in similar threads ( e.g. [Clone McAfee encrypted partition to SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/457845/clone-mcafee-encrypted-partition-to-ssd) ), Windows installed on properly cloned HDDs and SSDs used to start beautifully . . . until a few months ago.

Over the past several weeks I have tried many different cloning software and HDD / SSD duplicators (hardware) in vain to create usable carboncopies of encrypted HDDs / SSDs. (Windows OS does start but crashes halfway with a blue screen.) Does anybody happen to know if McAfee changed anything with respect to its endpoint disk encryption?

Comment: Why didn’t you suspend the encryption before you cloned the drive?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind comment. I have been simply trying to follow remarks posted at ''Best practices for manually decrypting an encrypted hard disk with Drive Encryption/Endpoint Encryption for PC'' ( https://kb.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB66433 ) which reads as follows.

quote

McAfee is not responsible for data loss from a Force Decryption. The product team recommends that you always perform a sector level backup (RAW/CLONE) of the hard drive to avoid data loss. Examples of products to use for sector level backup are Paragon, Acronis, or Ghost.

unquote

Answer (score -1):

Does this happen with Windows 10? If yes, then disable rapid start before cloning for a complete shutdown of the system. It worked for me!